# sql statement inside decode clause

Tags: sql, oracle

The decode works like this:

```
SELECT DECODE('col1', 'x', 'result1','y','result2') resultFinal 
 FROM table1;
```

It possible to accomplish this in sql:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (SELECT DECODE('col1', 'x' (someSql),'y',(someOthersql)) result 
          FROM table1)
```

So instead of result1 and result2 being fixed values, they would be sql statements.  If not possible, how can I achieve the same result without a stored proc.

EDIT: someSql and someOthersql are both complex queries with many joins returining many  but same number of cols with same col names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If *someSql* and *someOthersql* return **exactly** one row with one column, then this should work.

The following works for me:

```
select decode(col, (select 'foo' from dual), (select 'bar' from dual))
from some table
```

Comment: Yes. When sqls are simple like: select 1 from dual, it gives correct results. But the sqls in reality need to be complex with many joins. Many columns will be returned. What can be an alternative soln? When I run with the actual sqls, it gives: too many values

Comment: You cannot have a query that returns mutliple columns in the in the SELECT list of another statement. Even if it would be possible, how should decode work then? You'd supply multiple values in a place where only a single value is allowed. You should state your real underlying problem that you are trying to solve instead of a solution where you think you only need to fight some technical obstacles.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to create a PL/SQL procedure to handle the complex logic.